# TTL Policy in Firestore for a Numeric data type instead of Timestamp/DateTime data type

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection where I am storing Timestamp as a numeric data type instead of timestamp data type. Is there any way I can create a TTL Policy on that collection for this field?
I cannot change the data type to Timestamp now because my app is already in production.

Granted, this was a miss from my side for not making the field as Timestamp but I cannot find any way to do this with a numeric data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you're asking for (to delete outdated documents based on a numerical timestamp since the epoch, rather than a date/timestamp value) does not exist.

You could [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for it, but it's probably faster to change your code to store the value in the proper type going forward and either update the existing documents to match that type, or to clean those up with your own application code.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the case :(
Any ideas on how to update the type of an existing field in a collection in a programmatic way?

Comment: There is nothing special for this. [Read all documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) (in [pages if needed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)), and [update them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) one-by-one.